# Weekly average of daily panel data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, average

I have a large panel dataset of roughly 4million daily observations ([Overview of my Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuI8H.png)).

The variable symbol depicts the 952 different stocks contained in the data set and the other variables are some stock-related daily measures. I want to calculate the weekly averages of the variables rv, rskew, rkurt and rsj for each of the of the 952 stocks included in symbol.

I tried to group the dataset with group_by(symbol), but then I did not manage to aggregate the daily observations in the right way.

I am not very experienced with R and would highly appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple with the `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(ymd('2020-07-01'),ymd('2020-07-31'),by='day'),
           sybol = 'a',
           x = runif(31),
           y = runif(31),
           z = runif(31)
           )

df <- df %>%
  mutate(year = year(date),
         week = week(date),
         ) %>%
  group_by(year, week, symbol) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x),
            y = mean(y),
            z = mean(z)
  )
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   year, week [5]
   year  week symbol     x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2020    27 a      0.555 0.552 0.620
2  2020    28 a      0.652 0.292 0.461
3  2020    29 a      0.495 0.350 0.398
4  2020    30 a      0.690 0.495 0.609
5  2020    31 a      0.466 0.378 0.376
```